# How to solve the problem in excel: Macros are disabled

Tags: excel, vba, encryption, disable

I have an excel file with some macros inside where the sheets are protected with password and the workbook is encrypted with password as well. It opened and work well last week but today I encountered a problem.

The macros are disabled and I can't figure out how to enable it. Upon opening the file I only get a security warning stating "Macros have been disabled" with an 'Options" button. Clicking it I get the message stating that to run the Macros I need to remove encryption or permission restrictions on the file.

May I know why the file works well last week but now I need to remove the encryption/permission restriction in order to run the Macros inside the file? What can I do to my excel file setting? Any helps will be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try on File tab -> Option -> Trust Center ->Trust Center Settings -> Macro Settings -> Enable all Macros

Comment: Hi judaikun88, I already enable all the macros in the setting, but the problems still exist. Do you have any other suggestion that I can do?

Comment: @weizer The answer you need might be here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_winother-msoversion_other/problems-with-excel-files-containing-macros-when/554cecbd-06b2-40d1-abaf-13a30ab0910c

Answer (score 1):

This is a security measure. If macros are disabled you cannot programmatably enable macros. If that was possible then malicious code could enable itself. You need to manually enable macros as judaikun88 has described. Once enabled the setting will remain.

Note that you can also add trusted locations where macros are allowed to run.
Read more here:
https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/trusted-locations-and-excel-macros/

Comment: Hi StureS, I already enable all the macros under the setting but the problem still exist. Since I already enable all the macro under the setting, I believe that trusted locations will not work for this case as well. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: *I believe that trusted locations will not work for this case*. Well, "believe"? Could you please read the link and follow the guidelines first of all?

Comment: Then you have made something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going wrong, because I didn't make any changes to my window setting as well. I edited my question with the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Above options to change macro settings, then I did a file -> save a copy and that got rid of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to resolve that error by adding in a registry item to bypass the macro checks:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\Security\
Type: Dword
Name: ExcelBypassEncryptedMacroScan
Value: 1

Comment: I would be surprised if this works. The OP says *the workbook is encrypted with password* ... The question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261994/excel-password-removal)